# Java config equivalent of echcache.xml

Tags: ehcache

Is there a sample Java Config for a standard ehcache XML config file (ehcache.xml) . I am using Spring 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the provided documentation, there are some good code snippets, too: http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Specifically: "Adding and Removing Caches Programmatically": http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.5/code-samples#adding-and-removing-caches-programmatically